Why can't professors request tips for prompt service as many other jobs?
In many countries, hotel and restaurant waiters, hairdressers, taxi drivers request tips for their service. I am wondering why university professors cannot request tips for their extra time and effort on the prompt service?
For example, when the class finishes at the scheduled time, the professor is not supposed to do extra (is it?), but oftentimes he/she has to answer students' questions. It is often that students make appointments to ask questions for free. But this costs extra time and effort. (Imagine, can I make an appointment with a waiter for free, even if I have paid for the meal?)
Also, it is said that writing recommendation letters is the professor's duty. But serving customers is also the waiters and drivers' duty. The professor still can charge tips for the prompt service sending letters and so on.
Please don't get me wrong. I think not only the professors, but also doctors, lawyers, engineers, managers, every worker should have the right to request tips from their customers in addition to their regular charges, as long as it meets the definition of tips. When I was in America, it was said that tips are for "prompt services". What's wrong with that?

Hmmm, do waiters request tips?

As far as I'm aware, doing these things ARE part of the job. The time one spends in class is only a small part of what one is paid for. There's preparation (class lecture preparation, writing of major tests and numerous short quizzes), seeing students during office hours and otherwise as appropriate, grading tests, meeting with colleagues about course content and other issues (this can vary from nonexistent to major, depending on the course and university), and many other tasks.

Or, maybe just maybe, professors like many other people should do their job without wanting, much less expecting, tips. I think every professor I ever worked with would be deeply insulted by anyone offering a tip.

Your phrasing of "requesting tips" suggests you are confusing providing a tip (voluntarily, post-hoc, and for relatively unspecific "good service") with paying a bribe (negotiated upfront, explicitly for some specific help, and involuntary if you actually want to get your stuff done).

@JonCuster I have received small non-monetary presents after classes / graduation on occasion, even that already feels rather icky. And my university agrees - there is nowadays a policy in place that we are not allowed to take presents that exceed the value of a mid-range bar of chocolate from current or former students.

@xLeitix, I've received a gift or two from a cohort of students from a particular culture. The gift had minimal economic value, but was meaningful to those students who wanted me to have something to remember them by. One is still sitting on my tchotchke shelf after many (many) years. It wasn't icky, as it was heartfelt. Maybe the fact that it came from a group makes a difference. One semester I remember a group of students from that culture coming together for office hours and sitting around my feet to ask questions. They told me I was their "guru" and that this was typical in their view.

There are countries where no tips are given. I like that rather than wrangling for tips between now 12.5%-30%, depending on where. Just include all. Professors have enough to think about, so they would not want to burden themselves with the mental load of wondering whether they should answer this one more question or stay this minute more for squeezing out a few more dollars. They have enough to think about the next paper and proposal to submit...

@xLeitix - indeed, any potential conflict of interest ($$$ for grades) is a bad look.

Social customs aren't always explainable by logic.

I believe some years ago there was some sort of scandal in South Korea.  Parents would give financial "gifts" to the teacher, and in return the student would receive a better grade.

I understand this question to be soliciting opinions about a prevalent policy's appropriateness, rather than the top-line question read in a literal sense. StackExchange isn't really the best place for open-ended discussion questions.

"Requesting tips" for doing your actual job as a professor sets up a conflict of interest and is unfair to those who can't pay and advantages the wealthy. It would be an abomination, IMO.
Unlike waiters, professors are (generally) paid a living wage and have expectations, including answering questions and responding to student needs. Waiters, on the other hand, in the US, are often not paid a living wage and this is actually condoned in law. There are many other places where the treatment of waiters is different and tipping other than nominally is rare.
And, there are a few places where professors are greatly under compensated, but those tend to be places with unfair employment systems overall.
I suspect that, in the US, if a professor actually requested tips for what they are paid to do, they would be fired for moral failings. Extortion is not an educational value.
I hope you aren't considering this, either as a professor or as a student hoping to bribe a professor for something.

While, of course, perfectly appropriate, I wonder why the response does not excoriate the necessity of tips in the first place, not just in academia. Effectively, tips are an ill-defined service tax, ironically especially prevalent in a country where even tax-based healthcare are considered as a fundamental ill by many. So, rather than adding "service tax" to a hitherto untaxed profession, the question is why not to instead argue for its removal altogether and for making prices reflect the real cost of a service. Admittedly @Buffy may have read something else less appetizing into the question.

@CaptainEmacs, I limited myself to the question asked, but, yes, a system that requires tips so that service employees can have a living wage is an abomination. OTOH, I am a very high tipper and might be even in a different system. Some of these folks (waiters...) make my life better and easier and I'm more than happy to gift them something in appreciation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_economy.

I realised that you focused on the question which is legit. I just came from a visit in Australia which has a lot of things in common with the US. No tips. Wonderful. And the prices are still slightly elevated, but reasonable. Being nice should live on a separate dimension than money, or else, as long as enough money is paid, one could afford to treat people badly. I still felt something was missing from your response (which I do not disagree with, it was just missing something), but this has been addressed by the response by 'academic'.

I fully agree with Buffy's answer: that there is a huge conflict of interest.
Here is an additional factor. Compare a professor's job to, say, that of a restaurant waiter. If you're a waiter, then the happier the customers are, the better.
But as a professor, you must hold your students to high standards, you must tell some students that their work is inadequate, and at the end of the semester you must give low or failing grades to students who deserve it.
Also, you have a lot of conflicting demands on your time, and so you often must push back against excessive or unreasonable requests. Students might ask for a professor's cell phone number, or expect emails to be answered promptly even on weekends and evenings, but the general consensus is that professors should not give into such demands.
Altogether, professors don't generally have a "customer service" mindset, and often chafe at any notion that they should. So this is another reason why I would consider tipping to be wholly inappropriate, and why I would refuse any tip if offered.

Very important points!

The first point here seems by far the most important: Instructors are in a position of power over their students, due to setting grades, writing recommendation letters, etc.  A tipping system sets up a very clear conflict of interest.  The other points all seem secondary and more debatable; the power-dynamic conflict of interest seems a morally clear-cut and non-negotiable reason not to tip.

The thought of a grown adult making, at least in the US, well into 6 figure salary, taking tips from students, some of whom are legally not even adults, for doing their job "promptly"... especially in situations where the socioeconomic background of students varies wildly from below poverty line to wealthy... frankly it's a really gross thought for lack of better words.

Gross, but probably not entirely unheard-of. Just think of the recent "tipping your landlord" debate on social media.  https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/landlord-thinks-tenants-tip-him-194609266.html

Given this focus on the salary, would you feel different about it if it was an adjunct professor struggling to make ends meet?

@Anyon it would still be wrong. There is still a very big conflict of interest and power dynamic. The power dynamic of a student and an adjunct is far lower compared to a tenured prof, but nonetheless existent. So I suppose, to me, this scenario will range from very inappropriate to extremely inappropriate.


Please don't get me wrong. I think not only the professors, but also doctors, lawyers, engineers, managers, every worker should have the right to request tips from their customers in addition to their regular charges, as long as it meets the definition of tips. When I was in America, it was said that tips are for "prompt services". What's wrong with that?

There is no set definition of what tips "are for." There are legal definitions of what qualifies as a tip, but that's for the purposes of making sure restaurant owners aren't taking their waitstaff's tips.
It would be incredibly unethical for some of the professions you have mentioned to accept money in exchange for "prompt service", even beyond the disgusting notion of paying people who are already making obscene amounts of money even more money to be "prompt." Should you be able to slip a doctor $100  to get moved to the head of the line in the ER to see your sprained ankle, in front of someone who is having chest pains?
It would be beyond unethical for a professor to engage in these practices. Students are not a professor's customers - they are the professor's students (they may be customers of the university, but that's a different issue). Professors are in an extreme position of power over students already. Treating them differently because of socio-economic status is discrimination. Allowing them to take money for doing things "promptly" creates a perverse incentive for them to do things "slowly" until being tipped to do them promptly, and professors do not need yet another factor influencing how/when they are able to answer email/student questions.
A professor would also have to be insane to accept this kind of gratuity, as well. It is really incredibly easy for "this $50 is for answering my questions about material on the upcoming test promptly" to become "this $50 is for giving me an "A".
